How to format data layout using R similar to Excel
I need to format data using R dataframe and then put it into excel.
To achieve this in Excel I would do this:

create pivot table
go to Design --> Report Layout --> Show in Tabular Form
go to PolicyLayer column --> Field Settings --> Layout & Print --> check "Display Labels
from the next field..."
go to PolicyNumber column and check subtotals to None

But how can I achieve that using R?
Should I try to manipulate data in dataframe and then load to excel?
Or should I put raw data in excel first and then perform excel formatting using R?
This is my df:
df <- data.frame(
  CatNumber = c("CTE00555", "CTE00555", "CTE00555"),
  PolicyLayer = c("Multi Layer Policy #", "Multi Layer Policy #", "Multi Layer Policy #"),
  PolicyNumber = c("SBA1", "SBA2", "SBA3"),
  Insured= c("DisneyCo", "DisneyCo", "DisneyCo"),
  GrossP = c(35000, 4000, 1000),
  GrossComm = c(9000, 1000, 200)
)

df output looks like this:
CatNumber   PolicyLayer          PolicyNumber   Insured    GrossP   GrossComm
CTE00555    Multi Layer Policy #    SBA1       DisneyCo    35000    9000
CTE00555    Multi Layer Policy #    SBA2       DisneyCo    4000     1000
CTE00555    Multi Layer Policy #    SBA3       DisneyCo    1000     200

Need to format layout and load it to excel:
CatNumber   PolicyLayer          Insured        Sum of GrossP    Sum of GrossComm
CTE00555    Multi Layer Policy #                   40000          10200
              SBA1               DisneyCo          35000          9000
              SBA2               DisneyCo          4000           1000
              SBA3               DisneyCo          1000           200

This is how it should look in excel:


If you want to add totals in your dataset, you can do this:
df %>% bind_rows(., (.) %>% summarise(.by = c(CatNumber, PolicyLayer), across(where(is.numeric), sum)))

Usually though, in R, you don't have nested information within a cell of a data frame.
